# When does instantiation happens for explicit instantiation of a function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, instantiation, explicit-instantiation

Hi i am learning about **explicit instantiation**. And so reading different examples but in one example have some doubts. The example is given below and i have 2 doubts in this particular example.

File **Application.cc** contains:

```
extern template int compare(const int&, const int&);
int i = compare(a1[0], a2[0]);// instantiation will appear elsewhere
```

File **templateBuild.cc** contains:

```
template int compare(const int&, const int&);
```

Also note that the function template compare is:

```
template<typename T, typename F = less<T>>
int compare(const T &v1, const T &v2, F f = F())
{
  if (f(v1,v2)) return -1;
  if (f(v2,v1)) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. As you can see in the Application.cc file in the 2nd line it is written(as a comment) that *instantiation will appear elsewhere*. But here we are using the template function as `int i = compare(a1[0], a2[0]);` and we know that whenever we use a template function the compiler will instantiate it. So why is that comment written there? Also in the explanation it is written that

> When the compiler sees an instantiation definition (as opposed to a declaration), it
> generates code. Thus, the file templateBuild.o will contain the definitions for
> compare instantiated with int.

So my question is if the compiler generates code whenever it sees an instantiation definition and so templateBuild.o will contain the definition of compare instantiated with int then how can we use compare() in the Application.cc file using `compare(a1[0], a2[0]);`? I mean the compare() template is not yet instantiated so how can we use it before it is instantiated?

2. My 2nd question is that where should i write(put) the content of the compare() template. For example in a header file or in the Application.cc file? By the content of the compare() template i mean the 3rd block of code that i have given in the example.

Comment: To use (call) a function, only a declaration needs to be present in the corresponding translation unit. Which is (the part with `extern`). This declaration instructs on a compiler how to generate machine code for a function call, including passing arguments and optionally reading the returned value. There is no need for the function definition to accomplish this task.

Comment: _"we know that whenever we use a template function the compiler will instantiate it"_ — I don't think this is true. A compiler can instantiate a function template only if it sees its definition.

Comment: "code is generated only when we use a template (and not when we define it)" This is an exact quote from a C++ 11 book from a section talking about function templates. @DanielLangr

Comment: Note the following quote from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template: _An **explicit instantiation declaration** (an extern template) **prevents implicit instantiations**: the code that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation definition provided somewhere else in the program._ Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zxqozWMv7 (no machine code for `f<int>` generated). Your book seems to be a bit inexact. I guess it is because in the vast majority of cases in practice, templates are not instantiated explicitly. BTW, which book is that?

Comment: The book is the standard book(i assume) "C++ Primer Fifth eidtion". Also there 2 more two more things that are written there(which i find contradictory) which i am quoting below.Quote 1: "We can declare a function that is not defined so long as we never use that function". Quote 2: "when we call a function, the compiler needs to see only a declaration for the function". Now doesn't Quote1 and Quote2 contradict each other? Isn't calling a function using it? @DanielLangr

Comment: No, it doesn't. Once we call/use the function, its definition of course needs to exist. But it is needed not until the linking phase. A compiler does not need it when compiling (translating) a source file where the function is called.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are dealing with a case, where the function template is defined in a header file, which is then included into both source files. Something as (for simplicity, I removed the functional parameter):

```
// compare.h

template<typename T>
int compare(const T &v1, const T &v2)
{
  if (v1 < v2) return -1;
  if (v2 < v1) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

```
// Application.cc

#include <compare.h>

extern template int compare(const int&, const int&);
int i = compare(1, 2);
```

```
// templateBuild.cc

#include <compare.h>

template int compare(const int&, const int&);
```

Now, it is useful to visualize how *translation units* look like for both these source files.

1. Translation unit for `Application.cc`:

```
template<typename T>
int compare(const T &v1, const T &v2)
{
  if (v1 < v2) return -1;
  if (v2 < v1) return 1;
  return 0;
}

extern template int compare(const int&, const int&);
int i = compare(1, 2);
```

When a compiler translates (compiles) this translation unit, it sees only the **explicit instantiation declaration**. If it wasn't there, the `compare` function call would cause implicit definition instantiation. But since it is there, this implicit instantiation is avoided, as written [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template):

> An **explicit instantiation declaration (an extern template) prevents implicit instantiations**: the code that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation has to use the explicit instantiation definition provided somewhere else in the program.

Consequently, a compiler only generates machine code for calling `compare<int>` as it was a normal (non-template) function with its declaration but not definition in the translation unit.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/1c8jvvcv1

Note that there is no machine code generated for `compare<int>`.

2. Translation unit for `templateBuild.cc`:

```
template<typename T>
int compare(const T &v1, const T &v2)
{
  if (v1 < v2) return -1;
  if (v2 < v1) return 1;
  return 0;
}

template int compare(const int&, const int&);
```

Here, we have an explicit instantiation definition, which causes the function template to be instantiated as `compare<int>`.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/o9vxPvP75

Now, the machine code for `compare<int>` has been generated.

Comment: cppinsights.io might help to visualize: [With extern](https://cppinsights.io/s/ffdfe6c5), [implicit instantiation without extern](https://cppinsights.io/s/53b27b0a).

Comment: I think i am getting confuse about the exact workings of compiler and linker. So as i understand it these are the steps how this program(mainly) works. Step 1: The compiler sees the statement `extern template int compare(const int&, const int&);` which tells it that it doesn't need to generate code implicitly unless it encounters explicit template definition somewhere in the program(which can be other file). Step2: It sees the statement:`int i = compare(a1[0], a2[0]); ` but doesn't instantiate due to the reason given in step1. @DanielLangr

Comment: Step3: it sees `template int compare(const int&, const int&);` in templateBuild.cc and generates code(or instantiate compare<int>). Now my question is to initialize i in the statement `int i = compare(a1[0],a2[0]);` we need the result returned from compare<int> instantiation. So how is that result returned? Will this be the work of linker instead of the compiler? And is my 3 step compilation process correct. What will you add to the process? @DanielLangr

Comment: @JasonLiam Mechanisms for passing arguments to and return values from functions are called _calling conventions_ and are defined by the ABI of the system. For example, `int` return value on x86_64/Linux is passed in the `eax` register.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1)**

```
extern template int compare(const int&, const int&);
```

With this line, you can suppress the implicit instantiation of a template specialization or its members. That's what the comment in the second line means. In this current example, the explicit instantiation definition is in the **templateBuild.cc** file.
You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=only-explicit-instantiation-c).

**Question 2)**

You have to put the template class definition and declaration in the same (header) file.
For more details please have a look at [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#:%7E:text=A%20template%20is%20not%20a,%E2%80%9Cfill%20in%E2%80%9D%20the%20template.) page.

Comment: There is no class template involved in the question.